# "A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time" using HTTPClient for calling 3rd party url

Tags: c#, .net, azure, azure-functions, httpclient

I am facing some issue when calling third party API in Azure environment.

```
var request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, new Uri(tokenEndpoint, UriKind.Absolute)) 
{
    Content = new FormUrlEncodedContent(payload)
};

using var responseMessages = await clienthttp.SendAsync(request,
                              HttpCompletionOption.ResponseHeadersRead)
                             .ConfigureAwait(false);
```

We are trying to access External 3rd party API url  from AzureFunction in Azure Cloud.
Whenever we tried to do post request from Azure Function to 3rd party  API, it gives the following error:

> Error : *“A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected
> host has failed to respond.”*

Its working fine in local system but gives error when deployed in Azure.

Also we have tried with Addition of SecurityProtocol TLS, Extend the API Request Time, HTTPClientFactory using POLLY, Enabled CORS Policy but none of them worked.

Is there any need of configuration between Azurefunction and 3rd party API in Azure.

Comment: Sounds like a network / firewall problem.

Comment: Is the VPN connected to the local machine when accessing 3rd party API?

Answer (score 0):

Please check if the below steps help to fix the issue:

- Try Whitelisting your IP Address in the Azure Function App > Networking > Access Restrictions
- If you have integrated the Function App with Virtual Network, then check the NAT Gateway rules as well as whitelisting the static IP addresses on the Firewall side.